# Question on posting a variable to a php script using the .ajax method

Tags: php, jquery

I need help with posting a value to a php script from a js function called by an onclick event in an HTML page. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a link to the Google hosted jQuery library.

I am rendering a page with php with a submit button whose onclick action is seen below as updateSession() which posts a value to a php script that is supposed to update a MySQL table.

I can step through the script wile executing, using Fire Bug, but once it steps back out of the jQuery library no action or messages that I can see.

---------- script details

Part of the echo statement from the php rendered html page:

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"close\" onClick=\"checkCode()\"/>
```

The js function called by the submit action (i commented out my original attempt but left in place for comments):

```
function updateSession (){
    //$.post( "includes/update.php", { action: "y" });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "includes/update.php",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text",
        data: { 'action': 'y'},
        success: function( data ) { // for debugging
            alert( data );
        }
    });
}
```

The php script being called with the jQuery .ajax:

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    require("includes/config.php");
    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db) or die ( "Data Server Error");
    // connect to db
    // get session id from $_POST parm
    // add session id + validation marker to sessiondata table
    $action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
    //$idSession = SESSION_ID();

    $idSession = "sdfwe54645gaerg";
    $setCouponStateSql = "INSERT INTO appdata values ($idSession, $action);";
    $executeUpdate = mysql_query($setCouponState);

?>
```

Comment: Your code looks generally good.  What exactly isn't working?  What does the network tab in Firebug tell you about what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using firebug (use the 'net' tab) to see what URL is being posted by the AJAX call.

- If the URL doesn't look right, then you have an issue with your ajax call.
- If the URL looks correct, paste it into your browser and observe the behavior of your PHP code.

You should be able to debug from there.

Comment: Thanks for the firebug tip. Knowing the tools better helps. I really appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0):

i am not what exactly is the problem .. but the php script doesnt send any output so in js u wont be seeing anything in that alert(data); it should come back as an empty alert.

put echo "something"; in the php script at the end and then test.